# How to create stored procedure for alternative working Saturdays?

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure for displaying working Saturdays.

For example:

Last working Saturday `08/08/2015` (dd/mm/yyyy), then next working Saturday should be `22/08/2015` (dd/mm/yyyy)

It should omit between Saturday (`15/08/2015`). Likewise, I want to show for particular year

Comment: Start with the first working saturday in January and keep adding 14 till the date is less than or equal to 31st December

Comment: can u please add your sample for this question

Comment: How should the logic know that 8/8 is the working Saturday and not 15/8?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @start_sat_day DATE = Dateadd(d, -( Datepart(dw, Getdate()) % 7 ), Getdate());

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT @start_sat_day AS sat_days
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(dd, 14, sat_days)
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  Year(sat_days) = Year(@start_sat_day))
SELECT sat_days
FROM   cte
WHERE  Year(sat_days) = Year(@start_sat_day)
```

**Result  :**

```
sat_days
---------
2015-08-08
2015-08-22
2015-09-05
2015-09-19
2015-10-03
2015-10-17
2015-10-31
2015-11-14
2015-11-28
2015-12-12
2015-12-26
```

Comment: Oh! Yeah thanks for your valuable answer... It will generate automatically for every year?

Comment: It depends on the year present in your input `'08/08/2015'`

Comment: so manually, we have to give for every year. Is there any way to auto generate for corresponding year?

Comment: Clarify me. How it is starting from 08/08/2015. I think it is start day of a week. rite?

Comment: Its previous Saturday. When you run this query `Select Dateadd(d, -( Datepart(dw, Getdate()) % 7 ), Getdate())` you will always get previous Saturday

Comment: so if it is auto generated, for new year it will show from previous december month saturday also na?

Comment: If the last saturday is `2015-12-26` then you will get `2015-12-26` as result

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The assumption is, 3rd Jan 2015 was the first working Saturday.

```
DECLARE @firstsaturday date = '2015-01-03'

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT @firstsaturday AS StartDate
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(WK,2,StartDate)
FROM CTE
WHERE YEAR(StartDate) = '2015' 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE YEAR(StartDate) = '2015'
```

Comment: Now i dont want for particular year by giving input. I want this to be auto generate for every year

Comment: OK. Please post the code that you have so far, so I can understand your requirements better